# Hive - create table by select columns from different tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, window-functions, full-outer-join

Here are my hive tables:

table1:

```
|a |b |c |
----------
|a1|b1|c1|
|a2|b2|c2|
|a3|b3|c3|
|a4|b4|c4|
|a5|b5|c5|
```

table2:

```
|x |y |z |
----------
|x1|y1|z1|
|x2|y2|z2|
|x3|y3|z3|
|x4|y4|z4|
|x5|y5|z5|
```

Desired output:

```
|a |b |x |y |
-------------
|a1|b1|x1|y1|
|a2|b2|x2|y2|
|a3|b3|x3|y3|
|a4|b4|x4|y4|
|a5|b5|x5|y5|
```

is it really possible in hive? Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship between table1 and table2? What columns are you joining on?

Comment: What if the two tables have a different number of rows?

Comment: there is no relation between 2 tables, all i need is just pick few cols from one table and few from other and create another table, I will specify what all cols from each table, that's all.

Comment: it doesn't really matter for me if they do have different number of cols, all its need, specified cols must be present.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to "line up" the rows of both tables. Assuming that column `a` can be used to order the record in `table1` (resp column `x` in `table2`), you can use `row_number()` as follows:

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.x, t2.y
from (select t1.*, row_number() over(order by a) rn from table1 t1) t1
inner join (select t2.*, row_number() over(order by x) rn from table2 t2) t2
    on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

If the tables may have a different number of rows, and you want to retain "additional" rows, you can just change the `inner join` to a `full join`.